# Other Wi-Fi broadcasts are detected but not the local one

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm have use of a laptop:teaching purposes that periodically refuses to Link up to a specific Wi-Fi public access point at a given location. All other machines connect properly to the strong-enough signal

I have disabled/enabled the Wi-Fi driver, made sure the laptop was actually connecting (it sees many other local and nearby aps)and run windows diagnostics.

I fixed this once before but have no clue how I did it!

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest getting a program like acrylic wifi or inssider and checking out the channel that the desired wireless device is operating on.The first two options were for pc but if you have an android phone you can download netgear wifi analytics for free and you can find the channel there as well.  Your card may not be able to see this device on the current channel it is operating on . If you have access to this device change its wireless channel in the settings. Asking the admin to change it for you might be unlikely if you are not managing the device yourself and you are the only one affected. The other option would be to purchase a wireless dongle that attaches to your laptop , that dongle might be able to pick this signal for you if the other option of changing the channel of this wifi device is not available to you.